# How to solve equation $u^4 + bu + c=0 $

Tags: polynomials, roots, quartics

To solve for the roots of $x^2 + bx^\frac{1}{2} + c=0$,
I thought I might substitute
$u = x^\frac{1}{2}$ to get
$$u^4 + bu + c=0$$

But I don't really know what to do with that either. I plugged both into Wolfram Alpha, which provided some really long complicated solutions. However, I'm looking to implement this function in Julia and the translation to Julia would be ugly. I can determine a reasonable interval of interest, and can do a binary search for $0$ over that interval. So, I have that solution.

Is there a more elegant mathematical approach?

Comment: [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) might be of use.

Comment: I don´t think that there exists a closed form for the solution for  a polynomial with degree 4.

Comment: @callculus There is. But it is complicated.

Comment: @Szeto Nice to hear. It is worth to post an answer.

Comment: you better off using a numeric method. At most you'll have two roots.

Comment: See: [Ferrari's_solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Ferrari's_solution)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Writing $$bx^{1/2}=-c-x^2$$ so we get by squaring $$b^2x=c^2+x^4+2cx^2$$
and now good luck!

Comment: this may introduce false roots, I think substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$ is a better way

Comment: Ok, this can be true, but with the formulas by Farrari you will get all roots.

Answer (score 1):

The equation
$$u^4 + bu + c=0 $$
can be factorized as
$$\left( u^2+2s u +\frac{8s^3-b}{4s} \right)
 \left( u^2-2s u +\frac{8s^3+b}{4s} \right)=0
$$
where $s$ satisfies
$s^6-\frac c4s^2-\left(\frac b8\right)^2=0$, a cubic equation in $s^2$. The roots are then obtained via the familiar quadratic formula
$$u = -s \pm \sqrt{-s^2+\frac b{4s}},\>\>\>  s\pm \sqrt{-s^2-\frac b{4s}}
$$

Take the example $u^4+4u-1=0$ and solve for $s^2=\frac1{2}$.
Apply the formulas above to obtain the real roots

$$u=-\frac1{\sqrt2}\pm \sqrt{\sqrt2 -\frac12}$$